# OpenERP 7.0 configure mail servers

Tags: smtp, odoo

I have a problem configuring Outgoing Mail Servers.

When I click "`Test Connection`", I see "`Connection test succeeded! Everything seems properly set up!`", but when I try to create user, and I click "`Send reset password instructions by email`", I've got a message "`Cannot send email: no outgoing email server configured. You can configure it under Settings/General Settings.`"

I tried with various smtp servers and I got a clue when trying gmail smtp.

Google asked me:

> You can switch to an app made by Google such as Gmail to access your
>   account (recommended) or change your settings at
>   https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps so that your
>   account is no longer protected by modern security standards.

When I switched off the "*modern security standards*" I managed to send reset password instructions, however I can't use gmail for OpenERP.

I run OpenERP on my Synology NAS and there is something that smtp servers don't like. They allow to connect, but wouldn't allow to send emails.
IP is not and issue, as I tried smtp settings from account I actually have set up in my Outlook.

I will welcome any idea to solve it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the reason.
It makes no sense to me and I can't find the logic behind it, but this is causing the problem described.

The Company email has to be the same as ERP email servers.

Answer (score 0):

this actually happens when there is not email provided for the admin user. please provide the admin user the same email address used in outgoing mail server

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, but I solved it.

Please follow the below steps.

1. Go to 'My Account'
2. Please select the 'Connected apps & sites'
3. Then you will see the 'Allow less secure apps: ON' Please 'ON' that button.
4. Please try again to Press 'Test Connection' button.

Hope this will help you.